# Код с выделением памяти на СИ работает через раз

Tags: c, указатели

Доброго времени суток.

Пишу приложение для работы с простейшей базой данных, состоящей из 1 таблицы. Уже реализовал создание (пока что без сохранения в файл), добавление/удаление элемента и закрытие (освобождение памяти).

Но дело в том, что программа практически работает через раз, я подозреваю, что дело в realloc в функции add(). По моей задумке, если выделенная под элементы память заканчивается, то память должна пересоздаться размером большим на определенное значение, но что-то идёт не так.

Я вызываю функцию add в цикле 12 раз, соответственно на 10 раз выполнения функция должна автоматически выделить память большего размера, но это работает не всегда

Подскажите, пожалуйста

Вот код функции add():

```
int add (db *dbp, int size, float * vector){
    if (dbp->count_rows == dbp->max_count)
    {
            dbp->rows = (record *) realloc (dbp->rows, (dbp->max_count + DEFAULT_SIZE) * sizeof(record));
            if (NULL == dbp->rows)
            {
                    return 0;
            }

            dbp->max_count += DEFAULT_SIZE;
    }

    dbp->count_rows++;

    dbp->rows[dbp->count_rows].id = dbp->rows[dbp->count_rows - 1].id + 1;
    dbp->rows[dbp->count_rows].size = size;
    dbp->rows[dbp->count_rows].nums = (float *) calloc (size, sizeof(float));
    dbp->rows[dbp->count_rows].nums = vector;

    return 1;
```

}

Прикладываю весь код (pastebin)

[main.c](http://pastebin.com/Ht3eBYVx)

[db.h](http://pastebin.com/EUqjFAUk)

[db.c](http://pastebin.com/v7qEwaDk)

Comment: Я понимаю, если бы realloc возвращал NULL, но программа просто вылетает: "Завершена работа программы ..."

Comment: Код надо писать прямо в вопросе

Comment: Дело в том, что realloc пытается выделить непрерывный кусок памяти, но если её не хватит, то может возникнуть напредвиденное поведение. Воспользуйтесь malloc и memcpy, вместо realloc для решения Вашей проблемы.

Comment: Берите дебагер и проверяйте каждую подозрительную строчку кода.

Comment: @Umed у автора функция add вызывается 12 раз, соответственно realloc - 1 раз, размер структуры 12-16 байт (16  на 64 битной ОС), количество элементов 20. Это на какой такой конфигурации нету прямо на старте процесса 320 байт непрерывной памяти?

Comment: @zooZooz: Вы бы не прикладывали _весь_ код, весь его вряд ли будут читать. Лучше соорудите минимальный воспроизводящий проблему пример, который поместится в вопрос. Это увеличит шансы на то, что ваш вопрос заинтересует опытных участников.

Comment: @VladD, спасибо, впредь так и буду делать, а пока попробую то, что подсказал Umed

Comment: @sba, я тоже думал как Umed, но ведь 8 гигов оперативы..

Comment: @sba, согласен, погорячился. Но мало ли что там за конфига могла быть у автора и сколько раз он перевыделял память))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Функция `add` некорректная.

```
int add (db *dbp, int size, float * vector)
{
    if (dbp->count_rows == dbp->max_count)
    {
        dbp->rows = (record *) realloc (dbp->rows, (dbp->max_count + DEFAULT_SIZE) * sizeof(record));
        if (NULL == dbp->rows)
        {
            return 0;
        }

        dbp->max_count += DEFAULT_SIZE;
    }

    dbp->count_rows++;

    dbp->rows[dbp->count_rows].id = dbp->rows[dbp->count_rows - 1].id + 1;
    dbp->rows[dbp->count_rows].size = size;
    dbp->rows[dbp->count_rows].nums = (float *) calloc (size, sizeof(float));
    dbp->rows[dbp->count_rows].nums = vector;

    return 1;
}
```

Если `dbp->count_rows == dbp->max_count`, то, как говорится, поздно пить "Боржоми".:) Это означает, что вы уже предприняли попытку записи в память за пределы выделенной памяти.

Индексы в массиве начинаются с 0 и на единицу меньше размера массива.

Чтобы было понятно, представим, что текущее значение `dbp->count_rows` на единицу меньше значения `dbp->max_count`. В этом случае проверка

```
    if (dbp->count_rows == dbp->max_count)
```

даст отрицательный результат и управление перейдет на предложение

```
    dbp->count_rows++;
```

и `dbp->count_rows` благополучно станет равной `dbp->max_count` и будет осуществлена запись за пределы выделенного массива.

Далее, если вы делаете `realloc` то надо использовать другой указатель для выделенной памяти вместо `dbp->rows`,

```
dbp->rows = (record *) realloc (dbp->rows, (dbp->max_count + DEFAULT_SIZE) * sizeof(record));
```

Иначе в случае неуспеха распределения памяти значение исходного указателя будет утеряно и вы получите утечку памяти.

В данном фрагменте кода

```
dbp->rows[dbp->count_rows].nums = (float *) calloc (size, sizeof(float));
dbp->rows[dbp->count_rows].nums = vector;
```

вы выделяете память под `size` элементов типа `float`, но вместо того, чтобы скопировать эти элементы в только что выделенный массив, вы указателю
`dbp->rows[dbp->count_rows].nums` присваиваете значение указателя `vector`.

В результате происходит утечка памяти.

В других функциях, включая `main`, у вас также имеются серьезные ошибки.

Например, нельзя использовать функцию `memcpy`, когда участки памяти перекрываются. Вы должны использовать функцию `memmove`  В функции `close` вы освобождаете память, занятую `dbp->rows` , но не освобождаете память, выделенную для `nums`. В main вы освобождаете память, выделенную для `a`, но эта же память используется в поле `nums` и т.д.

Вам надо в данном случае выставлять свой код на код-ревью, а не в разделе вопросов.

Comment: То есть, в последних абзацах, вы говорите о том, что вместо присваивания указателя нужно через цикл копировать значения?

Comment: @zooZooz Конечно нужно копировать элементы, а иначе зачем выделять память и приводить к ее утечке?

Comment: @zooZooz, но это копирование можно осуществить и одним `memcpy()`. / А `dbp->count_rows++;` просто перенесите в конец `add()` -- перед return

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, спасибо большое

Comment: @avp, и вам спасибо)

Comment: @zooZooz Не за что. Мы, начинающие программисты, должны помогать друг другу.:)

Comment: Да, и еще: а где этот код-ревью найти?

Comment: @zooZooz Я знаю на родительском SO http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ , а есть ли на российском SO - не знаю. Может быть кто-нибудь подскажет.

Comment: в этой функции просто переставьте `dbp->count_rows++;` после всех операторов перед return;